# Change an object's implemented interfaces at runtime

Tags: java, types, dynamic-typing

Is it possible to dynamically add to the list of interfaces implemented by an object (such that `instanceof` returns true and casts don't fail)?

I have a set of objects whose types need to change dynamically during runtime. As their state changes, more of their methods/properties become valid. Currently, this is done in a "brute-force" way... all members are exposed, and calling the wrong one at the wrong time is a bug. Ideally, I would like to use static typing, and to pass these objects to methods which expect specific interfaces. The set of interfaces that an object implements will only increase, so old references would remain valid.

Is it possible to change an object's implemented interfaces at runtime, either using built-in reflection or via third-party bytecode manipulation?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what exactly you are trying to do, please elaborate. Either way, usage of reflection or `instanceof` is a code smell, and indicates your code should need some refactoring. There is likely a design pattern that do what you want.

Comment: Static typing implies compile-time enforcement, which is at odds with your desire for the type to change at runtime.

Comment: @amit, a "code smell" may or may not indicate a poor solution (or else it would be a syntax error). There are valid reasons to use `instanceof` to deduce an object's type at runtime.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It is not. I would like methods to take specific interfaces, but the caller should be able to pass in my dynamic objects as long as the object is in a state where it can implement the interface.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky It is usually a bad design, if you actually need the object's type - you should have carried it all the way (and not the interface). A good reusable and easy to maintain code usually avoids `instanceof`. If you have the interface type, you should only need what is exposed to you.

Comment: An old school way of doing things could be to have a Factory class of some sort. It would accept your "versatile" object as an Input, would check its properties / variables / state, and return an object / Proxy / whatever (Decorator, Wrapper class, ...) implementing the right interface based on your logic. (Not a perfect solution, but surely easier than messing with bytecode at runtime).

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky The point is - it is hard to advise if we don't actually understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The flow of the service should be such that after doing the check for completeness of instance (ex: fieldnames, its values) maybe using reflection, then you could do a cast dynamically without a check

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) but as the comments suggest - this is almost always not the best option.

You would be better to craft you object as multifaceted.

```
interface Interface1 {

    String getI1();
}

interface Interface2 {

    String getI2();
}

class Multifaceted {

    String i1;
    String i2;

    private final Interface1 asInterface1 = new Interface1() {

        @Override
        public String getI1() {
            return i1;
        }

    };

    private final Interface2 asInterface2 = new Interface2() {

        @Override
        public String getI2() {
            return i2;
        }

    };

    public Interface1 asInterface1() {
        if ( i1 == null ) {
            throw new InvalidStateException("I am not ready to be one of these yet!");
        }
        return asInterface1;
    }

    public Interface2 asInterface2() {
        return asInterface2;
    }

}
```